# Static richbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods

How can I make a `richtextbox` static in a form ( C#) in order to call it in other class and define a static method who can change it?

Comment: A better solution will be raising events from other classes and catch them in your form, and the form should update the richbox field.

Comment: You can call it by inheriting your class with `richtextbox` containing class. But why do you want it to make `static`?

Comment: What kind of form? You could have each instance of the form subscribe to an Event.

Answer (score 2):

With 3 steps:

1. Set your rich text box property `Modifiers` to `Public`
2. Make a static instance of your form:

   ```
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           _form1inc = this;
       }
       public static Form1 _form1inc;
   ```
3. Use it in other class

   ```
   Form1._form1inc.richTextBox1
   ```